# JAVA Spring JPA modifying native Query when using Pager

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm developing a REST service using Java Spring 8 and MariaDB 10.5 and following details:

java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)
Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

My repository is using a Native Query like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT v.id, user_id, aCode, name, "
            + "creationDate, guid, filename, total "
            + " FROM vContactListByACodeAndSearch v " + 
            " LEFT OUTER JOIN contact_Numbers ln ON ln.contactList_id = v.id " + 
             "WHERE aCode = ? " + 
            " AND CONCAT(IFNULL(v.name, ''), IFNULL(ln.contactNumber, '')) LIKE ? "
            + "GROUP BY v.id, v.user_id, v.aCode, v.name, v.creationDate, v.guid, v.filename, v.total")
Page<ContactListModel> findByACodeAndSearchString(String aCode, String search, Pageable page);
```

And my controller code is as follows:

```
List<ContactListModel> contactLists = repository.getContactListRepository().findByACodeAndSearchString(aCode, "%"+ search +"%", paging);
```

When running the REST service and calling the endpoint, this is what Logs show me:

```
2024-03-19 22:23:28.041 DEBUG 26128 -- [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [] org.hibernate.SQL                       .logStatement 94  : 
    SELECT
        v.id,
        user_id,
        aCode,
        name,
        creationDate,
        guid,
        filename,
        total  
    FROM
        vContactListByACodeAndSearch v  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        contact_Numbers ln 
            ON ln.contactList_id = v.id 
    WHERE
        aCode = ?  
        AND CONCAT(IFNULL(v.name, ''), IFNULL(ln.contactNumber, '')) LIKE ? 
    GROUP BY
        v.id,
        v.user_id,
        v.aCode,
        v.name,
        v.creationDate,
        v.guid,
        v.filename,
        v.total limit ?
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        v.id,
        user_id,
        aCode,
        name,
        creationDate,
        guid,
        filename,
        total  
    FROM
        vContactListByACodeAndSearch v  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        contact_Numbers ln 
            ON ln.contactList_id = v.id 
    WHERE
        aCode = ?  
        AND CONCAT(IFNULL(v.name, ''), IFNULL(ln.contactNumber, '')) LIKE ? 
    GROUP BY
        v.id,
        v.user_id,
        v.aCode,
        v.name,
        v.creationDate,
        v.guid,
        v.filename,
        v.total limit ?
```

which is fine.
But, right after, log shows the following query:

```
2024-03-19 22:23:28.449 DEBUG 26128 -- [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [] org.hibernate.SQL                       .logStatement 94  : 
    select
        count(v) 
    FROM
        vContactListByACodeAndSearch v  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        contact_Numbers ln 
            ON ln.contactList_id = v.id 
    WHERE
        aCode = ?  
        AND CONCAT(IFNULL(v.name, ''), IFNULL(ln.contactNumber, '')) LIKE ? 
    GROUP BY
        v.id,
        v.user_id,
        v.aCode,
        v.name,
        v.creationDate,
        v.guid,
        v.filename,
        v.total
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(v) 
    FROM
        vContactListByACodeAndSearch v  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        contact_Numbers ln 
            ON ln.contactList_id = v.id 
    WHERE
        aCode = ?  
        AND CONCAT(IFNULL(v.name, ''), IFNULL(ln.contactNumber, '')) LIKE ? 
    GROUP BY
        v.id,
        v.user_id,
        v.aCode,
        v.name,
        v.creationDate,
        v.guid,
        v.filename,
        v.total
2024-03-19 22:23:28.896  WARN 26128 -- [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  .logExceptions 137  : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2024-03-19 22:23:28.898 ERROR 26128 -- [http-nio-8090-exec-1] [] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  .logExceptions 142  : Unknown column 'v' in 'field list'
```

Which obviously fails because "count(v)" is invalid!

It seems to me that the issue is within the Pageable instruction, that needs to count number of values returned by the resultset (on the 1st execution) but instead of using count(v.id) instructions, somehow it changes to count(v) where v is the table alias and not a column!

Is this a bug?Any ideas on how to solve this?  Any patch? Am I doing something wrong related to the native SQL Query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use pagination in Spring Data JPA with an SQL query, Spring Data JPA internally generates a count query to determine the total number of results that match your criteria.

So I think you can create another query which returns the count, and JPA would use it instead.

For example:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT COUNT(*) " +
        "FROM vContactListByACodeAndSearch v " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN contact_Numbers ln ON ln.contactList_id = v.id " +
        "WHERE aCode = ?1 " +
        "AND CONCAT(IFNULL(v.name, ''), IFNULL(ln.contactNumber, '')) LIKE ?2 " +
        "GROUP BY v.id, v.user_id, v.aCode, v.name, v.creationDate, v.guid, v.filename, v.total")
long countByACodeAndSearchString(String aCode, String search);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I ended up doing, but using a countQuery annotation on the repository method. But still, Hibernate should be smart enough to understand that, in the code I shared, that using count(v)  is invalid because v is an alias and not a column name. IMHO this is a bug on Hibernate's SQL parsing code. And to prove it, I modified the original's query to use a different alias (like "potatoes" instead of "v") and Hibernate used count(potatoes) as expected.

Comment: for future memory, the method ended up as :
`
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
     countQuery= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [......]"
      value = "SELECT v.id, user_id, aCode, name, "
            + "creationDate, guid, filename, total "
            + " FROM vContactListByACodeAndSearch v " + 
            [...])
Page<ContactListModel> findByACodeAndSearchString(String aCode, String search, Pageable page); `

Comment: I am glad to hear that it works! And yes, I think Hibernate should improve in such kind of scenarios.